# Is this plant Monstera?

Tags: identification, houseplants

Is this Monstera Deliciosa? How to care for this plant? Location: Delhi.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The leaves are turning yellow on the edges.

Comment: this plant has definitely outgrown its pot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that is Tree Philodendron (Philodendron bipinnatifidum) (AKA Philodendron Selloum)  If grown outdoors it prefers morning sun with dappled shade the remainder of the day or dappled shade the entire day.  If the temperatures drop below 15°C (60°F), it should be brought inside in winter.  Inside in winter, it should be given a bright window with as much light as you can provide.   If it is summer, move it further into the room for windows with hot direct sunlight or move it by a east facing window in summer.

It prefers to stay moist, does not tolerate drought conditions. You can use many mediums to grow this plants.  It can be grown in traditional indoor potting mix with peat & perlite, or bark mixed with ground bark, coir husk of various size mixed with coir peat.  It need a medium that holds lots of water, but also is very free flowing.

[Philodendron bipinnatifidum](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=276569)

[Phil. bip. video repotting guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzSJO7V6bmc)

Comment: Will it die in very hot temp? 40C above or below? And if I keep it in full sun whole day, what will happen? Till now I kept it in medium indirect light.

Comment: And I can probably use vermiculite with this as it loves water?

Comment: Yes, it can live in very hot temperatures, but it needs to be in the shade or just morning sun.  If left in full sun the leaf will scorch.  That will stunt your plant.   They tolerate lower temps, but it is not the best growing conditions for this plant.  It can handle Zone 9, which still gets a frost.  But, only if you have a long summer.

Comment: You can use vermiculite, but with additional drainage matter.  Vermiculite holds so much water, but adds very little to drainage.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any place that gets dappled shade. So it is either direct sunlight with temperatures reaching up to 45 Degree C and shade with bright indirect light. I can provide it with morning sun but then complete shade for the rest of the day.

Comment: The second is perfect.  Full sun in morning and shade the rest of the day

Comment: It has been reclassified since then to *Thaumatophyllum bipinnatifidum*. :)